# Как вывести текущий объект массива в цикле

Tags: java

На входе получаем имя департамента, а на выходе должны быть имена всех рабочих из этого отдела. Не могу разобраться с написанием цикла который будет выводить имена этих рабочих. Пока написал только так, но цикл работает неправильно, выводит всех подряд.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter a department name: ");

        Employee [] employees = new Employee[5];
        employees[0] = new Employee("Worker1", Employee.Department.DEPARTMENT_1,1500);
        employees[1] = new Employee("Worker2",Employee.Department.DEPARTMENT_2,1700);
        employees[2] = new Employee("Worker3",Employee.Department.DEPARTMENT_3,2000);
        employees[3] = new Employee("Worker4",Employee.Department.DEPARTMENT_1,3000);
        employees[4] = new Employee("Worker5",Employee.Department.DEPARTMENT_3,1100);

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String worker = scn.nextLine();

        int workerCount  = 0;
        while (workerCount < employees.length) {
            if (worker.equals(Employee.Department.DEPARTMENT_1.name())) {
                System.out.println(employees[workerCount].getName());
                workerCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
//Так я получаю NullPointerException

     int workerCount  = 0;
        while (workerCount < employees.length) {
            if (worker.equals(employees[workerCount].getDepartmantName().name())) {
                System.out.println(employees[workerCount].getName());
            }
            workerCount++;
        }
```

```html
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private Department departmantName;
    private double salary;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Department getDepartmantName() {
        return departmantName;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDepartmantName(Department departmantName) {
        this.departmantName = departmantName;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }


    public Employee(String name, Department departmentName, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.departmantName = departmantName;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public enum Department {
        DEPARTMENT_1, DEPARTMENT_2, DEPARTMENT_3
    }


}
```

Comment: Странно, как он вообще из цикла у вас выходит. Вынесите для начала workerCount++ за пределы блока if

Comment: Прикрепите ваш класс Employee

Comment: Прикрепил класс

Comment: @Slaxor, Тогда можете прикрепить еще стэк трейс NullPointerException

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at EnumArraysAlgorithms.PrackticalTask.Test.main(Test.java:25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У Вас в конструкторе `Employee()` опечатка и из-за нее вы присваиваете имя департамента не из параметров, а самому себе.
2. См. выше по поводу счетчика. Я бы вообще от него отказался и использовал цикл foreach:

   ```
   for (Employee employee : employees) {
       if (dept.equals(employee.getDepartmantName().name())) {
           System.out.println(employee.getName());
       }
   }
   ```
3. Вас не запутывает то, что просите ввести имя департамента, а присваиваете введенное значение переменной `worker`?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, вынесите workerCount++ за пределы блока if, иначе вы будете двигаться по циклу только если имя совпало.
Во-вторых, сейчас вы сравниваете не с названием отдела текущего сотрудника, а только с первым отделом : `worker.equals(employees[workerCount].getDepartment().name())`